# Returning a List of Words from a File

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

My next project is writing a hangman game. I figured it would help me brush up on strings and file I/O.

Currently, i'm stuck on reading in a file of strings into a list. I'm trying to avoid global variables, so could someone point me in the right direction to make this (probably broken) code into a function that returns a list?

```
(defun read-word-list ()
  "Returns a list of words read in from a file."
  (let ((word-list (make-array 0 
                 :adjustable t
                 :fill-pointer 0)))
       (with-open-file (stream #p"wordlist.txt")
     (loop for line = (read-line stream)
        while line
          (push line word-list)))
       (select-target-word word-list)))))
```

Comment: How is the title of your question related to the text of your question?

Comment: I started asking one question, switched to another, and forgot to change it. Whoops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read-in the words as Lisp symbols, with just a few lines of code:

```
(defun read-words (file-name)
    (with-open-file (stream file-name)
      (loop while (peek-char nil stream nil nil)
           collect (read stream))))
```

Example input file - words.txt:

```
attack attempt attention attraction authority automatic awake 
bright broken brother brown brush bucket building 
comfort committee common company comparison competition
```

Reading the file:

```
> (read-words "words.txt")
=> (ATTACK ATTEMPT ATTENTION ATTRACTION AUTHORITY AUTOMATIC AWAKE BRIGHT BROKEN BROTHER BROWN BRUSH BUCKET BUILDING COMFORT COMMITTEE COMMON COMPANY COMPARISON COMPETITION)
```

The case could be preserved by enclosing the symbols in pipes (|) or declaring them as strings:

```
|attack| "attempt" ...
```

Reading without losing case:

```
> (read-words "words.txt")
=> (|attack| "attempt" ...)
```

Comment: If you use `read` in this fashion, you always should bind `*read-eval*` to nil.  On the other hand, I find it questionable to fill a package with a bunch of symbols from user input.  I would strongly prefer working with strings.

Answer (score 2):

If the words are one per line, you could do something like this:

```
(defun file-words (file)
  (with-open-file (stream file)
    (loop for word = (read-line stream nil)
          while word collect word)))
```

You could then use it like this;

```
(file-words "/usr/share/dict/words")
```